# How do I send nearby pixel data to a Pixel-Shader in Direct3D 11?

Tags: c++11, graphics, 3d, directx, sample

I've been going through these tutorials (only 2 links allowed for me): https:// code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef

and reading through the Direct3D 11 Graphics Pipeline: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I currently have a Pixel (aka. Fragment) Shader coded in HLSL, consisting of the following code:

```
//Pixel Shader input.
struct psInput
{
    float4 Position: SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color: COLOR;
};

//Pixel (aka. Fragment) Shader.
float4 PS(psInput input): SV_TARGET
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

What I (think I) would like to do is multisample and access nearby pixel data for each pixel in my Pixel Shader so that I can perform a sort of custom anti-aliasing like FXAA (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/sdk/11/FXAA_WhitePaper.pdf). From my understanding, I need to pass a texture to HLSL using PSSetShaderResources for each render, but beyond that I have no idea. So, my question is:

**How do I send nearby pixel data to a Pixel-Shader in Direct3D 11?**

Being able to do this kind of thing would also be extremely beneficial to my understanding of how c++ and HLSL interact with each other beyond the standard "pass some float4's to the shader" that I find in tutorials. It seems that this is the most crucial aspect of D3D development, and yet I can't find very many examples of it online.

I've considered traditional MSAA (MultiSample Anti-Aliasing), but I can't find any information on how to do it successfully in D3D 11 beyond that I need to be using a "BitBlt" (bit-block transfer) model swap chain first. (See DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC1 and DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC; only a count of 1 and a quality of 0 (no AA) will result in things being drawn.) Additionally, I would like to know how to perform the above for general understanding in case I need it for other aspects of my project. Answers on how to perform MSAA in D3D 11 are welcome too though.

Please use D3D 11 and HLSL code only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And again I answer my own question, sort of (never did use FXAA...). I am providing my answer here to be nice to those who are following my footsteps.

It turns out I was missing the depth stencil view for MSAA. You want SampleCount to be 1U for disabled MSAA, 2U for 2XMSAA, 4U for 4XMSAA, 8U for 8XMSAA, etc. (Use [ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to "probe" for viable MSAA levels...) You pretty much always want to use a quality level of 0U for disabled MSAA and 1U for enabled MSAA.

Below is my working MSAA code (you should be able to fill in the rest). Note that I used DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT and D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS, and that the Format values for the depth texture and depth stencil view are the same and the SampleCount and SampleQuality values are the same.

Good luck!

```
    unsigned int SampleCount = 1U;
    unsigned int SampleQuality = (SampleCount > 1U ? 1U : 0U);




//Create swap chain.

IDXGIFactory2* dxgiFactory2 = nullptr;

d3dResult = dxgiFactory->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dxgiFactory2));

if (dxgiFactory2)
{
    //DirectX 11.1 or later.
    d3dResult = D3DDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Device1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&D3DDevice1));

    if (SUCCEEDED(d3dResult))
    {
        D3DDeviceContext->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11DeviceContext1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&D3DDeviceContext1));
    }

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChain;
    ZeroMemory(&swapChain, sizeof(swapChain));
    swapChain.Width = width;
    swapChain.Height = height;
    swapChain.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChain.SampleDesc.Count = SampleCount;
    swapChain.SampleDesc.Quality = SampleQuality;
    swapChain.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChain.BufferCount = 2U;

    d3dResult = dxgiFactory2->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(D3DDevice, w32Window, &swapChain, nullptr, nullptr, &SwapChain1);

    if (SUCCEEDED(d3dResult))
    {
        d3dResult = SwapChain1->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISwapChain), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&SwapChain));
    }

    dxgiFactory2->Release();
}
else
{
    //DirectX 11.0.
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChain;
    ZeroMemory(&swapChain, sizeof(swapChain));
    swapChain.BufferCount = 2U;
    swapChain.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    swapChain.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    swapChain.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChain.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60U;
    swapChain.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1U;
    swapChain.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChain.OutputWindow = w32Window;
    swapChain.SampleDesc.Count = SampleCount;
    swapChain.SampleDesc.Quality = SampleQuality;
    swapChain.Windowed = true;

    d3dResult = dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain(D3DDevice, &swapChain, &SwapChain);
}

//Disable Alt + Enter and Print Screen shortcuts.
dxgiFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(w32Window, DXGI_MWA_NO_PRINT_SCREEN | DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER);

dxgiFactory->Release();

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    return false;
}






//Create render target view.

ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer = nullptr;
d3dResult = SwapChain->GetBuffer(0U, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&backBuffer));

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    return false;
}

d3dResult = D3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, nullptr, &RenderTargetView);

backBuffer->Release();

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    return false;
}


//Create depth stencil texture.

ID3D11Texture2D* DepthStencilTexture = nullptr;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthTextureLayout;
ZeroMemory(&depthTextureLayout, sizeof(depthTextureLayout));
depthTextureLayout.Width = width;
depthTextureLayout.Height = height;
depthTextureLayout.MipLevels = 1U;
depthTextureLayout.ArraySize = 1U;
depthTextureLayout.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthTextureLayout.CPUAccessFlags = 0U;
depthTextureLayout.MiscFlags = 0U;
depthTextureLayout.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthTextureLayout.SampleDesc.Count = SampleCount;
depthTextureLayout.SampleDesc.Quality = SampleQuality;
depthTextureLayout.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
d3dResult = D3DDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthTextureLayout, nullptr, &DepthStencilTexture);

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    return false;
}


//Create depth stencil.
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilLayout;
depthStencilLayout.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilLayout.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilLayout.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
depthStencilLayout.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilLayout.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilLayout.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilLayout.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilLayout.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilLayout.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilLayout.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
depthStencilLayout.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilLayout.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilLayout.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilLayout.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
ID3D11DepthStencilState* depthStencilState;
D3DDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilLayout, &depthStencilState);
D3DDeviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(depthStencilState, 1U);



//Create depth stencil view.

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewLayout;
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewLayout, sizeof(depthStencilViewLayout));
depthStencilViewLayout.Format = depthTextureLayout.Format;
depthStencilViewLayout.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
depthStencilViewLayout.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0U;
d3dResult = D3DDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(DepthStencilTexture, &depthStencilViewLayout, &DepthStencilView);

DepthStencilTexture->Release();

if (FAILED(d3dResult))
{
    return false;
}


//Set output-merger render targets.
D3DDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1U, &RenderTargetView, DepthStencilView);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do custom anti-aliasing like FXAA you'll need to render the scene to an offscreen render target:

-Create a `ID3D11Texture2D` with bind flags `D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET` and `D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE`

-Create a `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` and a `ID3D11RenderTargetView` for the texture created in step one.

-Render the scene to the `ID3D11RenderTargetView` created in step 2

-Set the backbuffer as render target and bind the `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` created in step 2 to the correct pixel shader slot.

-[Render a fullscreen triangle covering the entire screen](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/77670/8648) you'll be able to sample the texture containing the scene in the pixel shader (use the [Load()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function)

---

When you tried to do traditional MSAA did you remeber to set [MultisampleEnable in the rasterizer state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Does this all take place after my Draw calls?

Yes, I enabled it, but nothing gets drawn no matter what.

One of the things I'm having trouble understanding is when I need to render to my back buffer and the custom render target as well as how I can cause such events to take place at a particular stage.